# Unity world curve shader graph, how to start curving from a specific distance?

Tags: unity, shaders, unity-shader-graph

I've made simple world curving shader following some online tutorials and cleaning few things up. It's doing its job, however I have small issue where it curves objects that are very close to a camera. So, I am trying to figure out how to start curving only if objects are certain distance form the camera, lets say 20 units or more?

Below is a sub-graph I use to output a value for a vertex position i.e. curve world shader, this is the one I need to figure out how to modify

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you feed the z position into the Power node, subtract your minimum curving distance from the z to get a signed difference, and then run that through a Max node to take the greater of 0, or that z difference. Then pipe that clamped z value into the Power node.

If your camera is looking in the -z direction, then you'd do something similar, but *add* the minimum curving distance and then run it through a *Min* node instead. Either way, what you're doing is moving the vertex of the parabola forward or back along the z axis, then clamping everything closer to the camera to zero so you only see the further branch of the parabola.

Comment: This did the trick! Thank you